# Need to call method as soon as server starts responding to my HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest, .net-4.5, httpwebresponse

I need to call a method in new thread for ex: `mymethod()` as soon as server starts responding to my `HttpWebRequest`.

I am using below to send http requst and getting response.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(MyUrl);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
```

Now what i need is for my `request` when server starts responding as soon as i need to call a method `mymethod()` in new thread. But problem is I don't know how to detect that server has started responding (started responsestream ) to my request.
What is the way that tell me that server started responding and I can call my method.

Target framework: is .net framework 4.5 and my project is Windows Form application.

Comment: `HttpWebRequest`, `WebClient` and `HttpClient` don't offer such an event. They expose properties to read the processed response only. Why do you need this? You may want to use sockets, but you really don't want to.

Comment: What do you mean by "When the server starts responding"? You mean, once that server gets your request and starts processing it?

Comment: I mean when server accept my request and when it start giving response code then i need to call method.

Comment: @CodeCaster I can't explain why i need this but Is this not possible?

Comment: If you can't explain it, you don't need it. It is possible, but perhaps there's an easier fix for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I can think of is using `HttpClient` and passing a [`HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcompletionoption(v=vs.118).aspx), so you can start receiving the request once the headers are sent and later start processing the rest of the response:

```
public async Task ProcessRequestAsync()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(
           url, 
           HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    // When we reach this, only the headers have been read.
    // Now, you can run your method
    FooMethod();

    // Continue reading the response. Change this to whichever
    // output type you need (string, stream, etc..)
    var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: I need to post data with the request so how can I do that?

Comment: @Eplzong Look into the overload of [`SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193601(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ok thank and how can I get response cookie from HttpResponseMessage?

Comment: Please do ask another question if it is non-related to this. Comments aren't really the place for that.